# Using a vector to read in multiple csv files to r

Tags: r, csv, vector, user-defined-functions

I'm very new to R and trying to work out how to use a vector to read in multiple csv files. I want to create a vector with the files I want to read in, a vector with the names of the dataframes I will store the data in and a function which uses both of those to process multiple files. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
filevar<-c("study_data_raw.csv","study_data_cleaned.csv")
dfs<-c("study_data_raw","study_data_cleaned")
myfunc<-function(x,y) {
  y<- read.csv(file.path("C:/study_data",x))
  }
myfunc(filevar,dfs)
```

I get the following error "Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument"

My untrained eye can't find the logical problem and would welcome any guidance from more experienced r programmers.

Comment: There is already a lot answers on Stackoverflow for this.

Comment: Try `lapply(filevar, function(x) read.csv(file.path("C:/study_data", x), header=TRUE, sep=""))` replace `header=TRUE, sep=''` after checking your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Though I hate to tell someone new to R to use loops, that's your best bet here.

```
filevar<-c("study_data_raw.csv","study_data_cleaned.csv")
fileData <- list()
for(fileNum in 1:length(fileVar))
{
  fileData[[fileNum]] <- read.csv(file = paste0("C:/study_data/",filevar[fileNum]))
}
```

(note that the apply functions have loops in them, so they are not faster, and they are less readable/harder to debug)

I'd recommend this method since it allows you to reference the files numerically. If you'd prefer to have them named, do this

```
filevar<-c("study_data_raw.csv","study_data_cleaned.csv")
dfs<-c("study_data_raw","study_data_cleaned")
for(fileNum in 1:length(fileVar))
{
  assign(dfs[fileNum],read.csv(file = paste0("C:/study_data/",filevar[fileNum])))
}
```

Bonus points:
Also for any R user I'd recommend getting started with piping since it improves readability further.

```
library(magrittr) # or install.packages("magrittr") first
library(dplyr) # or install.packages("dplyr") first

filevar<-c("study_data_raw.csv","study_data_cleaned.csv")
dfs<-c("study_data_raw","study_data_cleaned")
for(fileNum in 1:length(fileVar))
{
  paste0("C:/study_data/",filevar[fileNum]) %>%
  readcsv() %>%
  assign(dfs[fileNum])
}
```

Comment: Why?  Just because someone is new to `R` doesn't mean they're new to programming, and for-loops are about as ubiquitous a concept as any software tool.

Comment: yeah, I meant that in R its good to get in the habit of vectorizing instead of using loops, since you're right: loops are ubiquitous and often new R programmers overuse them. That being said, reading csvs can't really be vectorized though so I guess theres not much point in my comment, except to draw attention to the fact that you should use loops as infrequently as possible in R. This would go without saying normally, but since he's a new useR I figured I'd mention it

Comment: this doesn't do what the OP asked for.  If they wanted a list back, `lapply` would be a better solution

Comment: Edited to include that way of doing things. I stand by my assertion that the apply functions are inferior to loops because they are less transparent (= harder to debug), and give you no performance benefit.

Comment: depends on what you want to get back.  If you want a list back, then `lapply(x, FUN)` is easier than `L <- vector("list", length(x));for (i in x) L[[i]] <- FUN())`.  I use `for` loops when I'm primarily looping for a side-effect.

Comment: *note that the apply functions have loops in them, so they are not faster...* That depends heavily on what you're actually doing